# What can we say about $\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}$ in this two-body problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque

I'm trying to answer some questions about this two-body homework problem. We establish that the attraction force between two particles is given by
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}_{12} =-k \left( \vec{r} - \frac{r}{v_0} \dot{\vec{r}}\right)
\end{equation}
where $k$ is some constant, $v_0$ is some constant velocity, $\vec{r} = \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2$, $r = \lvert \vec{r} \rvert$, and where $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$ are the position vectors of the two particles.

---

From here I want to know

> What's the internal torque of the system?
> Is the system conservative?

To do this, I calculated that the internal torque of the system is given by
$$
\vec{\tau}_{\text{int}} = \frac{kr}{v_0} \left(\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}\right) \tag{1}
$$
which tells me that the value of the torque depends on $\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}$, i.e if the vector that connects the particles and said vector's derivative are parallel or not.

To have some understanding of how this vector behaves, I established a differential equation for the two-body problem as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem#Displacement_vector_motion_(2nd_one-body_problem)). Denoting the reduced mass as $\mu$, we get
\begin{align}
\ddot{\vec{r}} = -\frac{k}{\mu} \left( \vec{r} - \frac{r}{v_0} \dot{\vec{r}}\right) \implies \left(\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}} \right)' = \frac{k}{\mu v_0} r \left(\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}\right) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where on the last step I crossed both sides of the equation with $\vec{r}$ and noticed that $\left(\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}} \right)' = \vec{r} \times \ddot{\vec{r}}$.

---

Here's where I got stuck. I can say that $\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}$ is parallel to its derivative, but beyond that I don't know what more I can say about $\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}$.

Does anyone have any other ideas of how I can conclude something from the previous equations? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that your force function is correct? The units aren't consist.

Comment: Filling in for a constant with units of (time)^-1 as @BillN suggests will give you physical intuition (a rotation frequency?). I would try polar coordinates. Two body problems cry out for polar coordinates.

Comment: @BillN, you're totally correct. I forgot a constant on one of the terms. I'll edit the question to correct this. Thank you!

Comment: @joigus, I tried to expand the equations in polar coordinates and obtained a pair of coupled differential equations for $r$ and $\theta$. However, I didn't notice how I could use this to argue about the behavior of $\vec{r} \times \dot{\vec{r}}$.